# Div-table css magic row styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've heard of some kind of div-table CSS magic, so I just found some tutorials because in my case I can't make a proper table and I made a structure which looks like this

```
<div class="body-div>
    <div class="cat-container">
        <div class="category"></div>
        <div class="category"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the containers are the columns and the product and category are the rows. I would like to make these div's look like a real table so I added this to my style.css.

```
.body-div {
    display: table;
}
.cat-container {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
}
.product-container {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
}
```

The `category` and the `product` doesn't have the same height. I've tried to add `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;` to the `category` and `product` but none of these worked, just messed up my design. My problem is the `product` div is bigger than the `category` most of the time makes the whole table ugly. And there could be difference between `product` and `product` height as well. So I need some kind of CSS or Javascript method which select each "rows" biggest height and makes the whole thing a table-like div.

Here is an image what I created:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex6G2.jpg)

Comment: So each row is a category and several products? I probably would have organized it the other way around where your table is a `div`, then each row is a sub-`div`, then each of those rows would contain column sub-`div`. That reflects the `table`, `tr`, `td` type of structure more directly and (imho) easier to follow. Thus, you'd have `<div class="table-body"><div class="table-row"><div class="table-cell">cell1 content</div><div class="table-cell">cell2 content</div>...` etc. The heading for the table would be its own `div` row.

Comment: if you need to show tabular data then a regular table is just fine

Comment: @insertusernamehere I've added

Comment: @lurker I know but I can only get columns from the database and it's a dynamic table

Comment: You have nothing constraining the height of your `div` elements in your CSS, so they are all whatever the size of the cell is. Is the table particularly large? If not, then you could read all of the elements in, then organize the HTML by rows rather than columns.